# Access is Denied Issue thrown at ChromeDriver Initiation step

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#, selenium-webdriver-c#, azure-devops

Azure DevOps is triggering and running tests on a VM.

All my tests are working fine on local machine.

On VM, While trying to launch Chrome browser using `ChromeDriver` and `WebDriverManager`, tests are failing at `LaunchChromeDriver` method with failure as **'Access is Denied'** at step new `ChromeDriver`(options);

This is how the method looks like:

```
public static IWebDriver LaunchChromeDriver()
{    
 try
 {
    new WebDriverManager.DriverManager().SetUpDriver(new ChromeConfig());
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    return driver;
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
    log.info("Exception is "+e);
    return null;
 }
}
```

Am I missing something or do I need to modify the code?

Did anyone experience the same?

Getting an exception as below:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied
> at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
> at OpenQA.Selenium.DriverService.Start()
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)

Comment: Check permissions on folder where chromium is located.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the chromedriver.exe executable file path:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Chrome\chromedriver.exe")
```

For Windows, Allow Read & Execute Permissions on chromedriver.exe for Everyone:

1. Right Click chromedriver.exe > Properties  On ChromeDriver
2. On ChromeDriver Properties Window > Security Tab, click Edit
3. On Permissions for ChromeDriver Window > Security tab, click Add
4. On Select Users window, set name to Everyone and click OK button
5. On Permissions for ChromeDriver Window > Security tab, make sure Read & Execute box is checked & click OK button
6. On ChromeDriver Properties Window, click OK button

[image]

For Linux:

1. Check you have installed latest version of chrome browser-> "chromium-browser -version"
2. If not, install latest version of chrome "sudo apt-get install chromium-browser"
3. Get the appropriate version of chrome driver from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
4. Unzip the chromedriver.zip
5. Move the file to /usr/bin directory sudo mv chromedriver /usr/bin
6. Goto /usr/bin directory and you would need to run something like "chmod a+x chromedriver" to mark it executable.
7. finally you can execute the code.

Answer (score 0):

If using Linux, removing and readding the driver NuGet packages will solve the permissions

Answer (score 0):

Just you can cut chromeDriver.exe from debug folder and paste it to another place, then rebuild the project again